# Android App crashes: Trying to make ListView with sections within ListFragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a ListView with sections within a fragment but it will always crash at the same point in my fragment (page3), the app crashes when it returns the rootView and after a looong time of debugging

Below my latest try (inspired by a tutorial I found on the internet):
My relevant xml files:

`item_view_stocks.xml` (the items of my listview):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_lasttrade"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_stockchangepercentage"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_lasttradetime"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_stockname"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_lasttrade"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_lasttrade"
    android:textColor="@color/light_text"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_stockchange"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_lasttradetime"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_lasttradetime"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_stockname"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:foregroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

item_view_stocks_separator.xml (the xml file for my separator item in the listview):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_section_text"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorAccent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_page3.xml (the xml file of my ListFragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#dcdcdc">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here the JavaCode for my CustomAdapter (here called StockAdapter):

```
public class StockAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public StockAdapter(Context context){
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public void addItem(final String item){
    mData.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addSectionHeaderItem(final String item){
    mData.add(item);
    sectionHeader.add(mData.size()-1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (rowType) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_stocks, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_stocks_separator, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                break;
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}
```

}

And now my Page3.java (its the ListFragment):

```
public class Page3 extends ListFragment {

private StockAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page3, container, false);

    mAdapter = new StockAdapter(this.getContext());
    for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
        mAdapter.addItem("Row Item #" + i);
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem("Section #" + i);
        }
    }
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

}

I really really appreciate every help and advice you can give me.
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
my logcat just says:
02-28 17:27:33.647 27910-27910/com.example(...) E/Dialog: show mWindowManager.addView RuntimeException

**EDIT:**
My logcat looks like this: [logcat]

I am so sorry, but I cannot show you any Stacktrace /:

Comment: What kind of crash?  Are you getting an exception?  Can you post your logcat output?

Comment: hey wyoskibum, my got a mWindowManager.addView RuntimeException

Comment: can you post the stacktrace related to the exception you posted?

Comment: it isn´t showing any stacktrace. In the logcat window, it just shows this line: 02-28 17:27:33.647 27910-27910/com.example(...) E/Dialog: show mWindowManager.addView RuntimeException